# How can I send an email to a user after their approval using PhpMailer

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmailer

I have a table displaying a record of registered users(pending approval). Consequently, I have created a function where I can approve their membership at the same time send them an email(**through email displayed on the the table**). However, while the user is successfully updated on the database, they do not get the email notification.
This is how I am getting the records from the database:

```html
                <?php echo form_open('controls/view'); ?>
                              <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <tr class="table table-dark">
                                    <th class="table-active"><b>Name</b></th>
                                    <th class="table-active"><b>Email</b></th>
                                    <th class="table-active"><b>Company</b></th>
                                    <th class="table-active"><b>Mobile Number</b></th>
                                    <th class="table-active"><b>Mpesa Code</b></th>
                                    <th class="table-active"><b>Action</b></th>
                                </tr>
                                <?php foreach ($snm_users as $user): ?>
                                    <tr>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $user['fname']; ?>"></td>
                                         <td><input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $user['email']; ?>"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="company" value="<?php echo $user['company']; ?>"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="mobile_number" value="<?php echo $user['mobile_number']; ?>"></td>
                                         <td><input type="text" name="mpesa" value="<?php echo $user['mpesa']; ?>"></td>
                                         <td><a href="#" class="btn-success" id="<?php echo $user['user_id']; ?>">Approve</a> </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                                </table>
                            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

I am using PHPMailer to send email and here is where I have my configurations to send email:

```html
            // SMTP configuration
            $mail->isSMTP();
            $mail->Host     = 'smtp.gmail.com';
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
            $mail->Username = 'kibete20@gmail.com';
            $mail->Password = '*******';
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
            $mail->Port     = 465;

            $mail->setFrom($this->input->post('email'), 'My Hub');

            // Add a recipient
            $mail->addAddress($this->input->post('email'));
            // Add cc or bcc

            // Email subject
            $mail->Subject = 'Application for Ehub Membership';

            // Set email format to HTML
            $mail->isHTML(true);
```

Comment: did you checked out the spam folder?

Comment: Not in the spam folder, I believe the problem is in the part I am adding the recepient, I don't seem to understand how to catch that the email of the user approved and pass it therein so that they can get the email notification

Comment: So what's the error? What does the debug output say (since you have it enabled)?

Comment: Hi everyone, I figured out how to do this...thanks all